# Displaying an uploaded image in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Well, this newbie is doing something wrong when displaying images uploaded to the server:

model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

controller (upload - called by the [HttpPost] public ActionResult Create):

```
public void Upload(Person person)
{
    var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Fotos"), filename);
    image.Save(path);
    person.ImageUrl = Url.Content(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/Uploads/Fotos", filename));
}
```

create view:

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { @encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false, includeFormTag: false, uploadText: "image")
    ...
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
    </div> 
}
```

So far, so good, the image is uploaded to the folder and the url is saved

Now, I want to see it in the Detail View

detail view:

```
<div class="display-foto">
    <img src="@Url.Content(Server.MapPath(Model.ImageUrl))" alt="IMAGE" />                         
</div>
```

Viewing the generated code, everything seems to be alright:

```
<img src="D:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CMI_AD\CMI_AD\App_Data\Uploads\Fotos\_nofoto.jpg" alt="IMAGE" />
```

But the fact is that nothing appears on the screen except the text "IMAGE".

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I've tried without the Server.MapPath, using the relative address "~\App_Data\Uploads\Fotos_nofoto.jpg" and the result is the same.

--- EDIT ---

@kmcc049: I've tried your suggestion creating a helper

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString MyImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        img.Attributes["alt"] = "[IMAGE]";
        img.Attributes["src"] = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(url, htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

the call in the view:

```
@Html.MyImage(Model.ImageUrl)
```

the generated code is

```
<img alt="[IMAGE]" src="/App_Data/Uploads/Fotos/_nofoto.jpg" />
```

but the result is the same: no image :(

**--- SOLVED ---**

Apparently the App_Data is not a good location to save uploaded files because accessing them will result an Error 403 - Forbidden. I move the files to ~/Uploads/Fotos and it works.

Comment: the img tag have a hard disk url, and not an http ...

Answer (score 3):

That's not a valid HTTP path. That's the path to the folder on your computer.

try the `UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl()` method instead
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.generatecontenturl.aspx

Comment: Another try: `@{ var imgPath = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(Model.ImageUrl, this.ViewContext.HttpContext); }
            <img src="@Url.Content(imgPath)" alt="[IMAGE]" />` Same result: [IMAGE]