# Display image from location stored in Database asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, razor

I have complete image location stored in `Database`.The image is stored in that particular location. I want to display the image in the view. How to do this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321383/displaying-an-uploaded-image-in-mvc-3-razor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the path is not within the site you need to do this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Image(int id)
{
    string imagePath = // get the image path by the id

    return File(imagePath, "image/jpg");
}
```

So what we have is a controller that will get the image path from the database, and return the file. Now this will return the file, but if you want to display it in the view, you would do this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", "ImageController", new { id = idOfImageInDB })" alt="Image Description" />
```

So what happens now is when the view is loading, it calls the Image action from `ImageController` and passes it `idOfImageInDB` (the database key of the image you want) and displays the image.

Note that you need to have `ImageController` be the name of the conctroller the `Image ActionResult` is in, and `idOfImageInDB` is the `int` that is used to find the image.

Comment: Didn't work at all. I don't have image in database but the complete location of the image as `D:\abc\zxy.jpg`. Now i need to render the image in the view.

Comment: The image path is not in the website folder, I'll rewrite my answer.