# render image on the razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using asp.net mvc3 to upload images to web server. Problem is in dev mode when displaying images on razor view I have following to render images

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Photos)
{                    
   <img src="@image.Path" />                    
}
```

On page source everything seems fine, html tags are rendered like

```
<img src="C:\Projects\MySite\Content\uploads\Jellyfish.jpg" />
<img src="C:\Projects\MySite\Content\uploads\Lighthouse.jpg" />
```

On disk drive location image is correctly uploaded so everything seems ok but photo is not rendered.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value of `@image.Path` should be relative to your website and not the full path to your hard-drive. From your model, the `Path` property should read

```
/Content/uploads/Jellyfish.jpg
```

or simply

```
/Jellyfish.jpg
```

and should be generated like this in your view

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Uploads/@image.Path")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path should correspond to your website, not your hard drive. The correct path would be: "/Images/Jellyfish.jpg". So upload it to a folder in your project and you should be fine!

Here is a complete example:
[Displaying an uploaded image in MVC 3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321383/displaying-an-uploaded-image-in-mvc-3-razor)